# How to retrieve the Hardware ID using EP_RegHardwareID() method of enigma protector?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve the hardware id from 'Enigma_ide.Dll', as documentation saying, the function doesn't have parameter, If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to the null terminated ANSI string. If the function fails, the return value is 0.
I'm trying the follow code:

This is the definition in c++

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllimport ) __stdcall PCHAR EP_RegHardwareID();
```

My Code in c#

```
public class Enigma_IDE
    {
        [DllImport("enigma_ide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern string EP_RegHardwareID();
    }
string hwId = Enigme_IDE.EP_RegHardwareID();
Console.WriteLine(hwId);
```

the string printed is empty, where am I mistaking?

Here is a link to the documentation

https://enigmaprotector.com/en/help/manual/53e596732704f7ac068c6e74cfdf1ba3

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and post the solution if someone need it.

The method mentioned above return a Empty string because the EXE file need to be protected with Enigma, only after protecting the file the method return a value.